# How to read in double digits instead of single digits?

Tags: python

I am creating a postfix calculator that performs simple (+, - , *, /) operations. Running this code and using two single digit numbers works fine. However, using a double digit number (15, 20, etc.), it stores the numeber as ['1,'5'] instead of 15 and then the operation is messed up. How can I fix this?

```
evaluation = Stack()

def main():
    expression = str(input("Enter an expression: "))
    expression = expression.replace(" ","")
    for x in expression:
        evaluation.push(x)
    while len(evaluation) > 1:
        check = evaluation.pop()
        if check == "+":
            first = evaluation.pop()
            second = evaluation.pop()
            temp = int(second) + int(first)
            evaluation.push(temp)
        elif check == "-":
            first = evaluation.pop()
            second = evaluation.pop()
            temp = int(second) - int(first)
            evaluation.push(temp)
        elif check == "/":
            first = evaluation.pop()
            second = evaluation.pop()
            temp = int(second) / int(first)
            evaluation.push(temp)
        elif check == "*":
            first = evaluation.pop()
            second = evaluation.pop()
            temp = int(second) * int(first)
            evaluation.push(temp)
        elif check != "+" or check != "-" or check != "*" or check != "/":
            evaluation.push(check)
    print("Answer:", evaluation.data[0])
```

Comment: are you separating the operators and operands by , or ' '(space) in the input expression?

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the whitespace from the expression but *use it* to `split` the expression into usable parts:

```
In [1]: '223 370 * 45 /'.split()
Out[1]: ['223', '370', '*', '45', '/']
```

Iterate over the list that you've now got. To check if a list item is an operator you can simply use `in`:

```
In [4]: '+' in '+-/*'
Out[4]: True
```

If the item is not an operator it must be a number, so use `float()` on it and push it on the stack.

Since all your operators that you have defined, you only have to pop the operands once. And since normal mathematical operators are also available as functions, you could use a dictionary to call them instead of writing a long if/elif;

```
In [1]: from operator import add, sub, mul, div

In [2]: ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': div}

In [3]: ops['+'](1, 3)
Out[3]: 4

In [4]: ops['/'](1.0, 3.0)
Out[4]: 0.3333333333333333
```

So a simple calculator function could be written like this;

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div

_ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': div}


def postfix(expr):
    """Evaluate a postsfix expression

    :param expr: The expression to evaluate
    :returns: result of the expression
    """
    items = expr.split()
    if not items:
        raise ValueError("Empty expression")
    stk = []  # A plain list works fine here.
    for i in items:
        if i not in '+-*/':
            # float() will raise an exception if it doesn't find a number.
            stk.append(float(i))
        else:
            try:
                b = stk.pop()
                a = stk.pop()
                stk.append(_ops[i](a, b))
            except IndexError:
                raise ValueError('Invalid expression; empty stack')
    return stk[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to this point:

```
elif check != "+" or check != "-" or check != "*" or check != "/":
        evaluation.push(check)
```

you actually push one symbol into your stack.
What you might do instead is keep reading symbols (digits) until you haven't encountered something else, then convert the whole string that you have read into an integer and push it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into trouble because you're iterating through each character in the input.

I'd do one of 2 things:
   - break up the input - ask for the first number, the operation, and the second number separately
   - iterate through each character in the input and determine what it is, then correct for it.

Keep in mind that you are going to want to make sure you account for the operator maybe being a \ and if you use that on two ints, you will get an int out instead of a float, which may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
expression = "1234+567"
sign_index = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'[+-/*]', expression)][0]
sign = expression[sign_index]
first_num = int(expression.split(sign)[0])
second_num = int(expression.split(sign)[1])
```